# StickyNote node label clearing

Tags: python, nuke

The overall idea I have is to eventually add a button to my stickyNote nodes when I create them that when clicked would run a script that would give me a pop up window allowing me to change the value. Second idea was I had was for it just take the value within the default created and have it be empty rather than having the default values that appear on creation of "type note here".

I have tried to just set the value to ("") in my mind nothing would be in there, but the node still creates with the "type note here"

```py
def setColor(R,G,B):
    return int("%02x%02x%02x%02x" % (R,G,B,1),16)

def StickyNoteOverride():
    nuke.thisNode()["tile_color"].setValue(setColor(R=(255*.298),G=(255*.298),B=(255*.298)))
    nuke.thisNode()["note_font_size"].setValue(60)
    nuke.thisNode()["note_font_color"].setValue(setColor(R=(255),G=(255*.624),B=(255*.0)))
    nuke.thisNode()["note_font"].setValue("Deja Vu Sans Bold")
    nuke.thisNode()["label"].setValue("")
        ####nuke.thisNode()['label'].setText("")
        ####nuke.thisNode()['label'].setText("1")

nuke.addOnUserCreate(StickyNoteOverride, nodeClass = "StickyNote")
```

My expected code so far does everything I want it too except for changing default on usercreate value to either nothing in the field, or to the value of 1 which I was using through the .setText to just get it to print anything in the field or change the field. .setText change was tried on an already created stickyNote to change the value. When running .setText("1), the value comes back with .getValue usage as having a value of 1 in the field. But the actual node did not change at all. And I am getting stuck in just changing this value of the label before I progress forward further with learning how to have it create a user defined button.

Answer (score 0):

It just works for both variants - for string value `"Lorem Ipsum Dolor..."` and for empty string `""`:

```
def stickyNoteOverridden():
    colour = int('%02x%02x%02x%02x' % (0,128,64,1),16)   # Greenish
    nuke.thisNode()["tile_color"].setValue(colour)
    nuke.thisNode()["note_font_size"].setValue(60)
    nuke.thisNode()["note_font_color"].setValue(100)
    nuke.thisNode()["note_font"].setValue("Deja Vu Sans Bold")

    # nuke.thisNode()["label"].setValue("Lorem Ipsum Dolor...")
    # nuke.thisNode()["label"].setValue("")

nuke.addOnUserCreate(stickyNoteOverridden, nodeClass = "StickyNote")
nuke.createNode("StickyNote")
```

A key moment here is to use `.createNode()` command:

```
nuke.createNode("StickyNote")
```

Tested it in NukeX 11v3.5 NC on macOS Mojave 10.14.6.